# Запрет деления на ноль Python Kivy

Tags: python, kivy

Проблема заключается в следующем, Я начинающий программист, и пока что мои мозги не могут сообразить как сделать в Python Kivy, что бы при делении на ноль допустим "5/0=" Выводилось на экран "Error". Так же если можно помогите сделать проверку на нажатие знака, так как на данный момент можно написать по типу "4++++---00+++++"

```
import kivy
from kivy.app import App

from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.config import Config
Config.set('graphics', 'resizable', "0")
Config.set('graphics', 'width', 300)
Config.set('graphics', 'height', 400)

class CalculatorApp(App):
    def update_label(self):
        self.lbl.text = self.formula

    def add_right(self, instance):
        if(str(instance.text).lower() == ')'): 
            if self.formula == '0':
                self.formula = ''
            self.formula += ')'
        else:
            self.formula += str(instance.text)
        self.update_label()

    def add_lefts(self, instance):    
        if(str(instance.text).lower() == '('):
            if self.formula == '0':
                self.formula = ''
            self.formula += '('
        else:
            self.formula += str(instance.text)
        self.update_label()
                
    def add_number(self,instance):
        if( self.formula == "0"):
            self.formula = ''

        self.formula += str(instance.text)
        self.update_label()

    def add_operation(self, instance):
        self.formula += str(instance.text)
        self.update_label()

    def add_pi(self, instance):    
        if(str(instance.text).lower() == 'π'):
            if self.formula == '0':
                self.formula = ''
            self.formula += '3.141592653589793'
        else:
            self.formula += str(instance.text)
        self.update_label()

    def calc_result(self, insstance):
        self.lbl.text = str(eval(self.lbl.text))
        self.formula = "0"

    def clearONE(self, instance):
        self.formula = self.formula[:-1] or '0'
        self.update_label()

    def build(self):
        self.formula = "0"
        bl = BoxLayout(orientation = "vertical")
        gl = GridLayout(cols = 4, spacing=3, size_hint = (1, .6) )

        self.lbl = Label(text ="0", font_size = 40, halign="right", valign='center', size_hint = (1, .4), text_size=(300 - 50, 400 * .4 - 50))
        pass
        bl.add_widget( self.lbl )

        gl.add_widget( Button(text ="<<", on_press = self.clearONE, background_color = [255, 0, 0, 1], background_normal = '') )
        gl.add_widget( Button(text ="(", on_press = self.add_lefts, background_color = [.79, .76, .88, 1], background_normal = "") )
        gl.add_widget( Button(text =")", on_press = self.add_right, background_color = [.79, .76, .88, 1], background_normal = "") )
        gl.add_widget( Button(text ="π", on_press = self.add_pi, background_color = [1, .58, 0, 1], background_normal = '') )

        gl.add_widget( Button(text ="7", on_press = self.add_number, background_color = [.2, .2, .2, 1], background_normal = '') )
        gl.add_widget( Button(text ="8", on_press = self.add_number, background_color = [.2, .2, .2, 1], background_normal = '') )
        gl.add_widget( Button(text ="9", on_press = self.add_number, background_color = [.2, .2, .2, 1], background_normal = '') )
        gl.add_widget( Button(text ="*", on_press = self.add_number, background_color = [1, .58, 0, 1], background_normal = '') )

        gl.add_widget( Button(text ="4", on_press = self.add_number, background_color = [.2, .2, .2, 1], background_normal = '') )
        gl.add_widget( Button(text ="5", on_press = self.add_number, background_color = [.2, .2, .2, 1], background_normal = '') )
        gl.add_widget( Button(text ="6", on_press = self.add_number, background_color = [.2, .2, .2, 1], background_normal = '') )
        gl.add_widget( Button(text ="-", on_press = self.add_number, background_color = [1, .58, 0, 1], background_normal = ''))

        gl.add_widget( Button(text ="1", on_press = self.add_number, background_color = [.2, .2, .2, 1], background_normal = '') )
        gl.add_widget( Button(text ="2", on_press = self.add_number, background_color = [.2, .2, .2, 1], background_normal = '') )
        gl.add_widget( Button(text ="3", on_press = self.add_number, background_color = [.2, .2, .2, 1], background_normal = '') )
        gl.add_widget( Button(text ="+", on_press = self.add_number, background_color = [1, .58, 0, 1], background_normal = ''))

        gl.add_widget( Button(text =".", on_press = self.add_number, background_color = [.2, .2, .2, 1], background_normal = '') )
        gl.add_widget( Button(text ="0", on_press = self.add_number, background_color = [.2, .2, .2, 1], background_normal = '') )
        gl.add_widget( Button(text ="=", on_press = self.calc_result, background_color = [.13,.88,.0, 1], background_normal = '') )
        gl.add_widget( Button(text ="/", on_press = self.add_number, background_color = [1, .58, 0, 1], background_normal = '') )

 
        bl.add_widget( gl )
        return bl

if __name__ == "__main__":
    CalculatorApp().run()
```

Comment: Спасибо, сейчас попробую.

Comment: в функции расчёта сделайте проверку, содержитсяли '/0' в строке формулы. если нет то эвал, если да то ерор.

Comment: Сделал как вы сказали, не получается.

Comment: покажите что сделали.ошибка выходит или не верный результат ? пишите подробнее

Comment: def calc_result(self, insstance):
  self.lbl.text = str(eval(self.lbl.text))
  self.formula = "0"
  if '/0' in formula: formula="error"

Comment: Но скорее это Я глупенький, и что то накосячил.

Comment: в вашем коде self.formula  а не формула. и этот иф выше написать, перед эвалом, а эвал запихать под else. простите, я без компа и не могу правильно оформить вам нормальный полноценный ответ с телефона.

Comment: Все отлично, заработало, спасибо, только на экран не выводится Error.

Comment: попробуйте добавить self.update_label() чтобы обновить отображение

Comment: Сделал, вывод пошел, добавив еще одну строку в коде. Мы можем переместится в какою либо соц.сеть? Для удобства?

Comment: Только вот теперь при решении любой задачи, например "5/3" Выводится Error

Comment: И все же спасибо за содействие.

Comment: ''Только вот теперь при решении любой задачи, например "5/3" ''  в таких случаях вместе с ошибкой добавляйте и код , чтобы исключить гадания и дать точный ответ.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

код запускал на pydroid, заявленый функционал работает.

```
import kivy
from kivy.app import App

from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.config import Config
Config.set('graphics', 'resizable', "0")
Config.set('graphics', 'width', 300)
Config.set('graphics', 'height', 400)

class CalculatorApp(App):
    def update_label(self):
        self.lbl.text = self.formula

    def add_right(self, instance):
        if(str(instance.text).lower() == ')'): 
            if self.formula == '0':
                self.formula = ''
            self.formula += ')'
        else:
            self.formula += str(instance.text)
        self.update_label()
        
    def add_lefts(self, instance):    
        if(str(instance.text).lower() == '('):
            if self.formula == '0':
                self.formula = ''
            self.formula += '('
        else:
            self.formula += str(instance.text)
        self.update_label()
                
    def add_number(self,instance):
        if( self.formula == "0"):
            self.formula = ''
        self.formula += str(instance.text)
        self.update_label()
        self.flag=1    #тут флаг чтоб сказать что последнее нажималась цифра

    def add_operation(self, instance):
        if self.flag==1:    #проверяем что было последнее число или операция
            self.formula += str(instance.text)
            self.update_label()
        elif len(self.formula)>1:
            self.formula=self.formula[:-1]
            self.formula += str(instance.text)
            self.update_label()
        self.flag=0    #тут флаг чтоб сказать что была операция

    def add_pi(self, instance):    
        if(str(instance.text).lower() == 'π'):
            if self.formula == '0':
                self.formula = ''
            self.formula += '3.141592653589793'
        else:
            self.formula += str(instance.text)
        self.update_label()

    def calc_result(self, insstance):
        if '/0' in self.formula:    #проверяем деление на 0
            #self.formula='Error'
            #self.update_label()
            self.lbl.text = 'Error'
        else:
            self.lbl.text = str(eval(self.lbl.text))
            if  self.lbl.text[-2:]=='.0':    #убираем у целых чисел лишнее
                self.lbl.text= self.lbl.text [:-2]
        self.formula = "0"

    def clearONE(self, instance):
        self.formula = self.formula[:-1] or '0'
        self.update_label()

    def build(self):
        self.flag=0    #добавляем флаг
        self.formula = "0"
        bl = BoxLayout(orientation = "vertical")
        gl = GridLayout(cols = 4, spacing=3, size_hint = (1, .6) )

        self.lbl = Label(text ="0", font_size = 40, halign="right", valign='center', size_hint = (1, .4), text_size=(300 - 50, 400 * .4 - 50))
        pass
        bl.add_widget( self.lbl )
        #ниже меняем у * - + / self.add_number на self.add_operation

        gl.add_widget( Button(text ="<<", on_press = self.clearONE, background_color = [255, 0, 0, 1], background_normal = '') )
        gl.add_widget( Button(text ="(", on_press = self.add_lefts, background_color = [.79, .76, .88, 1], background_normal = "") )
        gl.add_widget( Button(text =")", on_press = self.add_right, background_color = [.79, .76, .88, 1], background_normal = "") )
        gl.add_widget( Button(text ="π", on_press = self.add_pi, background_color = [1, .58, 0, 1], background_normal = '') )

        gl.add_widget( Button(text ="7", on_press = self.add_number, background_color = [.2, .2, .2, 1], background_normal = '') )
        gl.add_widget( Button(text ="8", on_press = self.add_number, background_color = [.2, .2, .2, 1], background_normal = '') )
        gl.add_widget( Button(text ="9", on_press = self.add_number, background_color = [.2, .2, .2, 1], background_normal = '') )
        gl.add_widget( Button(text ="*", on_press = self.add_operation, background_color = [1, .58, 0, 1], background_normal = '') )

        gl.add_widget( Button(text ="4", on_press = self.add_number, background_color = [.2, .2, .2, 1], background_normal = '') )
        gl.add_widget( Button(text ="5", on_press = self.add_number, background_color = [.2, .2, .2, 1], background_normal = '') )
        gl.add_widget( Button(text ="6", on_press = self.add_number, background_color = [.2, .2, .2, 1], background_normal = '') )
        gl.add_widget( Button(text ="-", on_press = self.add_operation, background_color = [1, .58, 0, 1], background_normal = ''))

        gl.add_widget( Button(text ="1", on_press = self.add_number, background_color = [.2, .2, .2, 1], background_normal = '') )
        gl.add_widget( Button(text ="2", on_press = self.add_number, background_color = [.2, .2, .2, 1], background_normal = '') )
        gl.add_widget( Button(text ="3", on_press = self.add_number, background_color = [.2, .2, .2, 1], background_normal = '') )
        gl.add_widget( Button(text ="+", on_press = self.add_operation, background_color = [1, .58, 0, 1], background_normal = ''))

        gl.add_widget( Button(text =".", on_press = self.add_number, background_color = [.2, .2, .2, 1], background_normal = '') )
        gl.add_widget( Button(text ="0", on_press = self.add_number, background_color = [.2, .2, .2, 1], background_normal = '') )
        gl.add_widget( Button(text ="=", on_press = self.calc_result, background_color = [.13,.88,.0, 1], background_normal = '') )
        gl.add_widget( Button(text ="/", on_press = self.add_operation, background_color = [1, .58, 0, 1], background_normal = '') )

 
        bl.add_widget( gl )
        return bl

if __name__ == "__main__":
    CalculatorApp().run()
```

1й вопрос деление на 0.
для этого в функции расчёта результата culc_result мы делаем проверку, содержится в строке формулы '/0' ? если есть, то выводим ерор. если нет то расчитываем результат и выводим.
бонусом добавил стирание пустой дробной части, например 6/3 теперь покажет 2 а не 2.0

2й вопрос предлагаю решить с помощью флага.
и для начала нужно разделить цифры от операций.нужные функции у вас уже были сделаны,осталось переназначить кнопки и заменить self.add_number на self.add_operation

далее вводим флаг=0. при нажатии цифры флаг=1. при нажатии операции проверяем флаг,если 1 то добавляем операцию, если 0 то ничего. данный вариант уже решает ваш вопрос, но можно немножко доработать.

меняем 'ничего не делать с флагом 0' на проверку длинны формулы и если длинна больше 1(уже есть какоето число и оператор) то мы стираем в формуле последний оператор и добавляем который нажали.
бонусом идёт что формула не может начаться с операции, а не числа(это когда длинна меньше 1).

#надеюсь доки понятно написал

Comment: Выражаю вам огромную благодарность за содействие и помощь Очень благодарен.

Comment: И все же можно с вами поддерживать связь в соц.сетях?